# How do you pass in a String variable value to another string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Basically I did this and I got an error:

```
NSString *searchWord = @"Lilwayne";

NSString *resourceURL = (@"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=546952635e22cc0182d85daceff34381&q=%@&format=json", searchWord);
```

Error is:

```
reason: 'Resource 'Lilwayne' is invalid because the scheme is not 'https'.'
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. However if I remove the "%@" and replace it with "Lilwayne" it works.

The reason why I am doing it this way is because I have a search feature in my app to search for songs using the `soundcloud sdk` and I want to dynamically change the value of the variable "searchword" to whatever the user typed in.

Comment: I'm curious…where did you get the idea that putting two strings inside () would cause them to be merged?

Comment: Loooool ! I'm new to iOS sorry for the nooby question ohwell :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `stringWithFormat`

```
NSString *resourceURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=546952635e22cc0182d85daceff34381&q=%@&format=json", searchWord];
```

Comment: It says No known classm method for selector 'stringwithformat'

Comment: Sorry, check it out now. Edited my answer (use Format not format) @Pizzy213codes

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a trip to the NSString class reference in the Xcode help system. In addition to stringWithFormat, as suggested by Basheer, There is a section on combining strings.